# Is there a possible attack on a MySQL database using an input window

Tags: exploit, sql-injection, mysql

My app has an input field that is used as a source for a HTML and PDF file.

I also store this input in my database.

My question is: **Is it possible to somehow write something in the text field which would then give data away or even possibly harm my database?**

The content itself doesn't really query anything, as it is just stored.

I do not know how to protect my data storage from potential attacks, and I would like to learn how to verify that my application is not vulnerable to (potential) attacks.

Comment: You've tagged this with SQLi, so it appears that you already know the dangers. So, your title ("are there attacks") doesn't match your body ("how do I test"). What is it that you want to know?

Comment: We can't tell you how to perform SQLi testing in a Q&A site. And we can't tell you what specific issues your app might have.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the recommendations on OWASP's SQL prevention guide [here](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Without knowing more about the application or infrastructure, OWASP would be your best bet to evaluate your code.